# how to extract pmt information from m2ts file?

Tags: video, metadata

I have several m2ts files - it's a 3D file actually which has dependent and base view. I need to extract data such as the Program Map Table (PMT) of each view like below picture.
[image: PMT Info]

is there any tool which can give such as above informations? I have been trying the ExifTool, ffprobe(maybe I don't know the cmd), MPEG-2 Transport Stream analyzer (trial), but no result.

Anyone can help? Thanks before in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a good tool or API, But (assuming your a programmer, being that this is stack overflow) you could write your own. Its not as difficult as it seems.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Specific_Information

Just start looking for TS packets with PID 0. This is your PAT. Parse the PAT to get the PID of of the PMT. Look for a TS packet with this PID, and parse the PMT.